# Currency in array value in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array that contains price so I want to add currency.

I google and find a way to use currency in react is to use `import react-format-currency`. but after I practice it was not what I wanted. indeed the price data has appeared with its currency but it is in the text box. all I want is data price using currency without text box. how is that possible?

**This is my array**

```
[
    {"item" : "abc", "price" : 10000,},
    {"item" : "def", "price" : 25000,}
```

**To display**

```
import Currency from 'react-format-currency';
----------------------------------------------
this.state.json.map((data, i) => {
    return (         
        <h6><Currency value={data.price} currency="IDR" /></H6>
    );
})}
```

Comment: Could you show the code for Currency component

Comment: i do like this step https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-format-currency

Comment: Maybe you should use another library/component.

Comment: can you suggest me another library/component to use currency in react?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React intl](https://formatjs.io/react/v1/) to show formatted number/currency.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { IntlProvider, FormattedNumber } from 'react-intl';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
     name: 'React intl example'
   };
   this.data = [
    {
     "item": "abc",
     "price": 10000,
     "currency": "IDR"
    },
    {
     "item": "def",
     "price": 25000,
     "currency": "USD"
    }];
 }

 render() {
   return (
    <div>
     <Hello name={this.state.name} />
      {
       this.data.map((d, i) => {
         return (
           <h6 key={i}><FormattedNumber value={d.price} currency={d.currency} style="currency" /></h6>);
       })
      }
    </div>
   );
  }
 }

 render(
   <IntlProvider locale='en-US'>
    <App />
   </IntlProvider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
 );
}
```

Example - https://react-xhehe2.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

You might not need other third-party packages just for this. Use built-in `Intl.NumberFormat` for this:

```
const formatCurrency = (amount, currency, locale = "en-us") =>
  new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { style: "currency", currency }).format(amount);
```